# What does this small Fortran assembly code change mean?

Tags: assembly, fortran, x86-64, gfortran

I am working on changing a program from fixed format '.f' to a free format '.f90' and mainly use a program called findent. I have checked the changes it did to a file and all of them seem to be just doing proper replacing of comments and using '&' for line continuation.

However, when I disassemble the newly created object files I get a small difference in the disassembly code. I save it from the object files by running 'objdump -d' in the terminal.
The change is in this line:

```
 af0:   c7 85 30 fd ff ff 69    movl   $0x69,-0x2d0(%rbp)
```

becomes:

```
 af0:   c7 85 30 fd ff ff 5d    movl   $0x5d,-0x2d0(%rbp)
```

I don't know what changing 69 to 5d means, so far I can only assume its an adress label?
I used gfortran 7.5.0 to compile, and have an Intel i3-3110M, 64 bit OS, x64-based processor.

Comment: Did you disassemble a `.o` instead of a linked executable?  If so, use `objdump -drwC` to check relocations, like maybe a different offset into an array?  Unless it's a placeholder for a 32-bit absolute address in a `.o`, it's definitely not the address of a label / symbol.  It's storing an immediate integer value (sign-extended from 32 to 64 bits) to the stack (a local variable), either 0x69 = 105 or  0x5d = 93.  Addresses are usually somewhere near `0x401000`, or else they don't fit in 32 bits at all.

Comment: Yes, I didn't even know that's the name of what I was doing, I'm new sorry. I did disassemble a '.o' file. I will try and see what -drwC gives, thanks.
Would it be possible to point to me some material for the syntax of this?

Comment: the man page for [`objdump`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html) documents those options.  Or do you mean for the asm syntax?  Intel syntax is probably better documented than the default AT&T syntax; use `objdump -drwC -Mintel`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for links to guides and official docs.

Comment: Thank you! I meant the syntax of the asm.